# Reading specific column from excel file using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a folder with full of excel files and subfolders.Subfolders also contain excel files.

Using os.walk() i have been able to go through each subfolder and get the data from that excel file.My problem is , i want to take only mobile numbers column from all excel files and store them in database. Issue with that is , column name for mobiles number is different in each excel file and there are thousand excel files.

So i decided to get columns by its datatypes and length. (e.g. if column datatype is integer and length of each cell in that particular column is 10 then i would push that data.)

But i don't understand how to do this. I looped though columns and rows but all i got is repeatative data or error. Can someone please help me out with this ? Would be glad if you helps cause i am doing this since two days but failing. Thanks in advance.

```py
 def file_access(file_path_list):
    for path in file_path_list:
        if path.endswith(('xlsx' , 'xls' , 'XLS')):
            print '------------------------------\n\n'
            folder = path.split('/')[-2]
            sheet = path.split('/')[-1]
            print folder , sheet

            df = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name=None, header=None)

            # Here i am trying to get data from df object but failing to do so.
            # You can suggest me code from this stage.
```

Comment: Please post the error you get

Comment: Index out of range.when i do it in xlrd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain just phone number in many excel files you can try the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
import os

mydir = (os.getcwd()).replace('\\','/') + '/'

#Get all excel files include subdir
filelist=[]
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(mydir):
    for file in files:
        if (file.endswith('.xlsx') or file.endswith('.xls') or file.endswith('.XLS')):
            filelist.append(os.path.join(path, file))
number_of_files=len(filelist)

# Get data of cells from excel
data=[]
for i in range(number_of_files):
    #df.append(pd.read_excel(r''+ mydir +filelist[i]))
    df=pd.read_excel(r''+filelist[i])
    l=len(df.iloc[0])
    for n in range(l):
        if len(str(df.iloc[0][n])) >= 10:
            data.append(df.iloc[:][df.axes[1][n]])
            break
res=[]
for i in range(len(data)):
    res.append(data[i].values.tolist())
print(res)
```

To get all phone data from different column's name, it's used the length of phone number to differentiate to other column data. For this case i has used the length of phone number used in my country that is 11 in length (ex: 82330403045).

Output:

```
>>> data
[0    82330403045
1    82330403046
2    82330403047
3    82330403048
Name: Phone, dtype: int64, 0    82330403049
1    82330403050
2    82330403051
3    82330403052
Name: PhoneCell, dtype: int64]

>>> res
[[82330403045, 82330403046, 82330403047, 82330403048], [82330403049, 82330403050, 82330403051, 82330403052], [82330403049, 82330403050, 82330403051, 82330403052], [82330403045, 82330403046, 82330403047, 82330403048], [82330403049, 82330403050, 82330403051, 82330403052], [82330403049, 82330403050, 82330403051, 82330403052]]
```

You can use this output data for your database.

My Excel files:

[image]

Book1.xlsx file:

[image]

Book2.xlsx file:

[image]

Comment: Ok got it. your code is working awesome. But it is showing dtype as object.Although i am getting all the data i want. Thanks a ton friend. You dont know how much you have helped me.

Comment: you can add this to omit the dtype in your list : `list(data[i])`. i is a number for the length of data

Comment: is there any way to remove line ```Name: Phone, dtype: int64, 0    82330403049``` from output. i want just numbers nothing else. there is one contact also in that line. also want to remove the numbering index.

Comment: you can try: res=[] => for i in range(len(data)): res.append(data[i].values.tolist()) => print(res). Just add this code at the end of code above.

Comment: Like you said , you used length of the phone number to differentiate between other columns data. But what if other column also has text data which is less than 10 ?

Comment: you must make sure that the length of phone number is always same, because it's used to differentiate phone column to other column. So the program knows where is the position of phone number if we don't know the phone column's name.

Comment: problem is sometimes it also has country code with like 91XXXXXXXXXX or +91XXXXXXXXXX or 91-XXXXXXXXXX. I think this is the only way to do this.

Comment: oh i see, to solve that problem, the important point is searching for the country code in each column (not only length of phone text), you can make dynamic search. For example you can make a function that is used to search country code in each column by inserting the country code parameter.